# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, Objective-C question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, exc-bad-access

Hey, I'm new to Objective-C and as well as programming with Cocoa at all.. anyways my code looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
printf("how many address would you like to input?\n");
int numAddresses;
scanf("%i", &numAddresses);
char *inputString;

NSMutableArray * arrayOfBooks = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < numAddresses; ++i) {
 book * f = [[book alloc] init];


 printf("Please input the name of contact %i\n", i+1);
 scanf("%s",inputString);
 [f setName: inputString];

 printf("Please input the address of contact %i\n", i+1);
 scanf("%s", inputString);
 [f setAddress: inputString];

 printf("Please input the birthday of contact %i\n", i+1);
 scanf("%s", inputString);
 [f setBirthday: inputString];

 printf("Please input the phone number of contact %i\n", i+1);
 scanf("%s", inputString);
 [f setPhoneNumber: inputString];

 [f print]; 

 [arrayOfBooks addObject:f];
 [f release];
 }

for(int i = 0; i < numAddresses; i++){
 [arrayOfBooks[i] print];
```

}

```
return 0;
 }
```

I'm basically just making an address book. When I input the first name, it throws an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error. Why?

```
#import "book.h"


@implementation book

-(void) setName: (char*) nameInput{
name = nameInput;

 }

-(void) setAddress: (char*) addressInput{
address = addressInput;
```

}

```
-(void) setPhoneNumber: (char*) phoneNumberInput{
phoneNumber = phoneNumberInput;
}

-(void) setBirthday: (char*) birthdayInput{
birthday = birthdayInput;
}

-(void) print{
printf("Name: %s\n", name);
printf("Address: %s\n", address);
printf("Phone Number: %s\n", phoneNumber);
printf("Birthday: %s\n", birthday);
 }

@end
```

EDIT: I no longer get the error.. but now I have a new problem. It prompts me for the name input, then instantly prompts me for the address input before I have a chance to do anything. Why could this be happening?

Comment: Not related to your EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, but if you're actual goal is to make an address book application, you should probably use the AddressBook framework.

Comment: Also, you should always check the return value of `scanf`. `scanf` returns the number of items that were successfully parsed, so in your code, each invocation of `scanf` should return 1. If it doesn't return 1, that means an error occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good idea is to use [`fgets()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) instead of `scanf()`. Any whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines etc.) will cause `scanf()` to stop parsing, which—based on the input you are trying to obtain—is probably not what you want.

Use `fgets()` like this:

```
char lineBuffer[100]; // or some number large enough

puts("Enter something:");
if (fgets(lineBuffer, sizeof lineBuffer, stdin))
{
    // lineBuffer contains the input, but it also contains the '\n' at the end.
    doSomething(lineBuffer);
    // etc. etc.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

"inputstring" is just a char * - it is unassigned, and has no storage associated with it.

You have to pass it a pointer to an *array* of sufficient size, of use the "a" modifier and pass a *pointer to* a pointer to a char for scanf to allocate for you.

See the man page on scanf http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/scanf.3.html

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense.. but it just brings me to a new problem I'm having. Once I have input the name/address/etc. it sets them, but all of them are somehow set to whatever I input last.

Comment: You're re-reading to the same buffer - then uour "set" routines are just pointing them all to that same buffer. You need to *copy* the data to *unique* NSStrings.